# Design Question - What language/platform for a apps that display like a web, parse log files and update databases?

Tags: parsing

Just like the title describe, I plan to build an app that mainly to parse string from log files of multiple formats, updates value to database for record keeping. At the same time, the apps needs to manage the file like moving it to a file server/zipping for space storage and lastly displaying the status of the operation like how a web apps can do?

My operating OS is Windows based and I am looking for alternative besides using VB.Net. I am trying to take this task as an opportunity to learn a new programming language. Can someone give a suggestion? I am familiar with PHP, basic C and some beginner level of VB/VB.net.

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing log files I would suggest using Microsoft's Log Parser: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en.

It will allow you parse your log files with a pretty powerful SQL query like syntax.  It has hooks that you use from VB.NET.  And you can use your VB.NET to manage moving the files around.